# Get number of assertions in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, minitest

We are working on migrating Rails application from 2.3 to 3. The tests are written using minitest. There are many errors in the tests itself so as we fix some errors, we have more number of assertions to test. We would have correct number of assertions if we fix all errors.

But is there any way we can get total number of assertions written even if there are errors in tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each test will stop at the first assertion that fails. So if you have more than one assertion in a test the number will grow as the earlier assertions start to pass.

The number of assertions shows is the number of assertions that were executed, not the number in the test code. There is no way that I am aware of to get the number of assertions in the test code, regardless of passing or not. Why do you want this? What are you hoping to learn from this?

Comment: We have to give status of the work to client(non-technical) by number of test passing/failing/errors. As we fix errors unchecked assertion would run and might have some more errors or failures. So client gets impression that there is little progress in terms of stats.

Comment: The status of your work is probably better measured in the number of errors and failures that Minitest shows at the end of each test run.  As you clear these, it's an indication that the application is getting closer to a migrated state - at least to the extent that your tests cover the code base.  The absolute number of assertions doesn't really say anything definite about where you are in that process.